# Make tag [oidc] a synonym of [openid-connect]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I ran into a question tagged [oidc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oidc) today which is a common-ish shorthand for the openid-connect federation protocol.  Can we alias these two?

[openid-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openid-connect) is the correct master tag.

Comment: Sorry that this request got missed. Before I pull the trigger, can I get you to quickly look through and confirm that all of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boidc%5D+-%5Bopenid-connect%5D&mixed=0) are indeed about OpenID Connect? If not, the stragglers should be manually retagged before we complicate doing so with a merge.

Comment: The tag description is pretty clear, and all questions clearly loop in related tags (oauth2.0, authentication, authentication vendors, etc.) and/or auth-related terms. @CodyGray

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the tag description, but just because that's correct doesn't mean that people out there in the wild are actually using the tag correctly. Experience says that far too many askers completely ignore the tag description when choosing tags. :-( Anyway, thanks for confirmation...tag merge coming live to you soon.